Spliting a JSON list obj into multiple based on values in python
I have JSON object something like below,
Data = [
    {
        'Name': 'A1',
        'Value': 10,
        'Type': 'AAA'
    },
    {
        'Name': 'A1',
        'Value': 20,
        'Type': 'AAA'
    },  
    {
        'Name': 'B1',
        'Value': 10,
        'Type': 'AAA'
    },
    {
        'Name': 'C1',
        'Value': 10,
        'Type': 'BBB'
    },
    {
        'Name': 'D1',
        'Value': 10,
        'Type': 'BBB'
    }
]

And i would like to split the object into a list based on "Type" and then based on the "Name" also to something like below,
Data = {
    'AAA': {
        'A1': [
            {
                'Name': 'A1',
                'Value': 10,
                'Type': 'AAA'
            },
            {
                'Name': 'A1',
                'Value': 20,
                'Type': 'AAA'
            },          
        ],
        'B1': [
            {
                'Name': 'B1',
                'Value': 10,
                'Type': 'AAA'
            },      
        ]
    },
    'BBB': {
        'C1': [
            {
                'Name': 'C1',
                'Value': 10,
                'Type': 'BBB'
            }   
        ],
        'D1': [
            {
                'Name': 'D1',
                'Value': 10,
                'Type': 'BBB'
            },      
        ]   
    }
}

To achieve this, so far i have tried looping over the whole data and then splitting them into separate objects based on the "Type" and then create a unique list of "Name", then iterating over the newly created objects to split them based on the Name.
I was doing something like this,
tTmp_List_1 = []
tTmp_List_2 = []

tTmp_Name_List_1 = []
tTmp_Name_List_2 = []

for tValue in Data:
    if (tValue['Type'] == 'AAA'):
        tTmp_List_1.append(tValue)
        tTmp_Name_List_1.append(tValue['Name'])

    if (tValue['Type'] == 'BBB'):
        tTmp_List_2.append(tValue)  
        tTmp_Name_List_2.append(tValue['Name'])          

tTmp_Name_List_1 = list(set(tTmp_Name_List_1))
tTmp_Name_List_2 = list(set(tTmp_Name_List_2))


From the above "tTmp_Name_List_1" and "tTmp_Name_List_2", i am about to iterate over the list and then match the matching names with the initial Data object to come up with separated list objects based on the names and then set it back with something like this
tTmp_Dict = {}
for tTmp_Name in tTmp_Name_List_1 :
    tTmp = []
    if (Data['Name'] == tTmp_Name):
        tTmp.append(Data)
    
    tTmp_Dict.append(tTmp)

Can someone kindly suggest me or help me with a more better way of doing this.
Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks,

I see that you have edited your question after my answer, to change the output to a list.  you cant have a key:value pair inside a list. You will get a syntax error, Key-value pairs not allowed inside a list.

okay, understood.. Thank you

Try this.
organized_data = {}
for item in Data:
    item_type = item['Type']
    item_name = item['Name']
    
    if item_type not in organized_data:
        organized_data[item_type] = {}
    
    if item_name not in organized_data[item_type]:
        organized_data[item_type][item_name] = []
    
    organized_data[item_type][item_name].append(item)

# Output the organized data
print(organized_data)


thank you for the answer. What would i have to do to change the item_type from a dict to a list in ur code

What you asked for as a result is not valid json, as your list contains key value pairs. I assume that is why @Nesi built it this way.

from collections import defaultdict
data = 'your nested dict'

output_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
for element in data:
    output_dict[element['Type']][element['Name']].append(element)
    
output = {k : dict(v) for k, v in output_dict.items()}
print(output)


Try this
for item in Data:
    result.setdefault(item['Type'], {}).setdefault(item['Name'], 
       []).append(item)

The setdefault method simplifies the creation of nested dictionaries by initializing keys if they don’t exist.
